# Is there ParitionKey input In upsertItem in cosmos sql api in java sdk?

Tags: azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-sqlapi

Is there any paritionKey input in upsertItem in cosmos sql api in java sdk.
because CosmosContainer provide only two methods 1) upsertItem(Item) and 2) upsertItem(Item, CosmosItemRequestOptions).

Comment: what would partition key check do?

Comment: @MarkBrown My bad,  I was trying to ask partition key input in upsert ,  or does it retrieve from item itself ? because replace , create all other methods have explicit partition key input ?

Comment: I took a look at the SDK source and the method only has those two so it does not specifically have a param for partition key as the .NET SDK does so it probably derives this from the passed in document. https://github.com/Azure/azure-cosmosdb-java/blob/master/sdk/src/main/java/com/microsoft/azure/cosmosdb/rx/AsyncDocumentClient.java#L530

Comment: @Mark Brown  , I was thinking whether create / replace (having explicit partition key) is more efficient than upsert. Or it will be equivalent .

Comment: @MarkBrown I mean the partitionkey  is getting utilized or not in case of update or is it just id of the document?

Comment: They are only more efficient if you know the item is there or not because they throw an error on Create if it's already there or on Replace if it is not. Meaning you have to then make a second call.

Comment: @MarkBrown But upsert is still utilizing the partition key to locate the item position?

Comment: It must be. Easiest way to know is to test.

Comment: @MarkBrown I am working with java sdk and new to it , Can u suggest me how to test it ?

Answer (score 0):

Sure, just clone and try the Java SDK samples [here](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/azure-cosmos-java-sql-api-samples).